# pandas read_json returns object instead of datetime64 on some datetime64 columns

Tags: pandas, to-json

I have a DataFrame I'd like to serialize to JSON, and be able to read it back in a DataFrame. There are 2 datetime64 columns, but one of them is being returned as an object. I'm also losing the timezone info, but I see from [How do I keep the timezone of my index when serializing/deserializing a Pandas DataFrame using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493423/how-do-i-keep-the-timezone-of-my-index-when-serializing-deserializing-a-pandas-d?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C35.7963), that I can't do that.

```
wxdata.info()
pd.read_json(wxdata.to_json(date_format='iso')).info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9853 entries, 0 to 9852
Data columns (total 30 columns):
 #   Column                          Non-Null Count  Dtype                     
---  ------                          --------------  -----                     
 0   time_of_day                     9853 non-null   datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
 1   temp1                           9853 non-null   float64                   
 2   wind_chill                      9853 non-null   float64                   
 3   heat_index                      9853 non-null   float64                   
 4   dew_point                       9853 non-null   float64                   
 5   degree_day                      9853 non-null   float64                   
 6   density_altitude                9853 non-null   float64                   
 7   wet_bulb_globe_temp             9853 non-null   float64                   
 8   adjusted_altitude               9853 non-null   float64                   
 9   SAE_correction_factor           9853 non-null   float64                   
 10  rel_humidity                    9853 non-null   int64                     
 11  inst_wind_speed                 9853 non-null   float64                   
 12  inst_wind_dir                   9853 non-null   float64                   
 13  two_min_rolling_avg_wind_speed  9853 non-null   float64                   
 14  two_min_rolling_avg_wind_dir    9853 non-null   float64                   
 15  ten_min_rolling_avg_wind_speed  9853 non-null   float64                   
 16  ten_min_rolling_avg_wind_dir    9853 non-null   float64                   
 17  sixty_min_winddir_atpeak        9853 non-null   int64                     
 18  sixty_min_peak_windspeed        9853 non-null   float64                   
 19  ten_min_winddir_atpeak          9853 non-null   int64                     
 20  ten_min_peak_windspeed          9853 non-null   float64                   
 21  ten_min_wind_gust_time          9853 non-null   datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
 22  rain_today                      9853 non-null   int64                     
 23  rain_this_week                  9853 non-null   int64                     
 24  rain_this_month                 9853 non-null   int64                     
 25  rain_this_year                  9853 non-null   int64                     
 26  rain_rate                       9853 non-null   int64                     
 27  raw_barom_pressure              9853 non-null   float64                   
 28  barom_press                     9853 non-null   float64                   
 29  solar_radiation                 9853 non-null   int64                     
dtypes: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern](2), float64(19), int64(9)
memory usage: 2.3 MB
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9853 entries, 0 to 9852
Data columns (total 30 columns):
 #   Column                          Non-Null Count  Dtype              
---  ------                          --------------  -----              
 0   time_of_day                     9853 non-null   object             
 1   temp1                           9853 non-null   float64            
 2   wind_chill                      9853 non-null   float64            
 3   heat_index                      9853 non-null   float64            
 4   dew_point                       9853 non-null   float64            
 5   degree_day                      9853 non-null   float64            
 6   density_altitude                9853 non-null   float64            
 7   wet_bulb_globe_temp             9853 non-null   float64            
 8   adjusted_altitude               9853 non-null   float64            
 9   SAE_correction_factor           9853 non-null   float64            
 10  rel_humidity                    9853 non-null   int64              
 11  inst_wind_speed                 9853 non-null   float64            
 12  inst_wind_dir                   9853 non-null   float64            
 13  two_min_rolling_avg_wind_speed  9853 non-null   float64            
 14  two_min_rolling_avg_wind_dir    9853 non-null   float64            
 15  ten_min_rolling_avg_wind_speed  9853 non-null   float64            
 16  ten_min_rolling_avg_wind_dir    9853 non-null   float64            
 17  sixty_min_winddir_atpeak        9853 non-null   int64              
 18  sixty_min_peak_windspeed        9853 non-null   float64            
 19  ten_min_winddir_atpeak          9853 non-null   int64              
 20  ten_min_peak_windspeed          9853 non-null   float64            
 21  ten_min_wind_gust_time          9853 non-null   datetime64[ns, UTC]
 22  rain_today                      9853 non-null   int64              
 23  rain_this_week                  9853 non-null   int64              
 24  rain_this_month                 9853 non-null   int64              
 25  rain_this_year                  9853 non-null   int64              
 26  rain_rate                       9853 non-null   int64              
 27  raw_barom_pressure              9853 non-null   float64            
 28  barom_press                     9853 non-null   float64            
 29  solar_radiation                 9853 non-null   int64              
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), float64(19), int64(9), object(1)
memory usage: 2.3+ MB
```

As you can see, the first datetime64 column returned as an object instead of a datetime64. Doing this without the date_format='iso' switch, 'time_of_day' returns as int64, instead of datetime64.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm also wondering if perhaps this is because 'time_of_day' is the first column, which might be used as an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was it. I rename the 'time_of_day' column to 'timestamp', and both columns are now datetime64.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-json-reader

> Note

Large integer values may be converted to dates if convert_dates=True and the data and / or column labels appear ‘date-like’. The exact threshold depends on the date_unit specified. ‘date-like’ means that the column label meets one of the following criteria:

it ends with '_at'

it ends with '_time'

it begins with 'timestamp'

it is 'modified'

it is 'date'

Comment: The question now becomes: Can pd.read_json() use dateutil.parser.isoparse() to return a datetime object since I used pd.to_json(date_format='iso') ?

Answer (score 0):

You could supply the `errors='coerce'` parameter to the date conversion method.  Entries that are not convertible will be returned as NaT (not a time).  Then you can see the problematic items.  For example:

```
df['time_of_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_of_day'], 
                                   errors='coerce',
                                   exact='True',
                                   format='%Y-%m-%d' # provide your format here
                                  )
```

Comment: I'm reading in the initial data using read_csv with parse_dates. How would that work?

Comment: I read in the data with read_csv  w/o parse_dates, then tried your suggestion. I didn't get any bad records.

Comment: I think I know why one of the columns was read in as  datetime64. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-json-writer) is because that column ended with "_time"

Comment: Good observation!  Default behavior isn't always exactly what we think.

Comment: I think this still may be a bit of a bug in read_json().  My json did not have a large integer value (like an epoch time), but a ISO 8601 formatted string. e.g.: "time_of_day":{"0":"2020-06-15T16:41:52.000Z","1":"2020-06-15T16:42:52.000Z". An obvious "date-like" column shouldn't have to rely on the column name to be interpreted as a datetime.